# How to count inner XML elements with restriction to outer elements

Tags: java, xml, dom, count

I have a question on how to count elements in other elements by filtering the outer element by attribute. I have the following XML document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="no"?>
<DSCT2C>
    <TESTSTEPS APPLICATION="UGS">

        <TESTSTEP ORDER_NUMBER="0">
            <EN>Common Test</EN>
            <DE>Allgemeiner Test</DE>

            <TEST NEED_FUNCTION="true" FUNCTION_NAME="functionName">
                <DESCRIPTION>
                    <DE>Hallo</DE>
                    <EN>Hello</EN>
                </DESCRIPTION>
                <FILES>
                    <FILE>test.prt</FILE>
                    <FILE>test.drw</FILE>
                </FILES>
            </TEST>
            <TEST NEED_FUNCTION="false">
                <DESCRIPTION>
                    <DE>Hallo2</DE>
                    <EN>Hello2</EN>
                </DESCRIPTION>
                <FILES>
                </FILES>
            </TEST>
        </TESTSTEP>

        <TESTSTEP ORDER_NUMBER="1">
            <EN>Just a test</EN>
            <DE>Nur ein Test</DE>

            <TEST NEED_FUNCTION="true" FUNCTION_NAME="functionName123">
                <DESCRIPTION>
                    <DE>Hallo</DE>
                    <EN>Hello</EN>
                </DESCRIPTION>
                <FILES>
                    <FILE>test.prt</FILE>
                    <FILE>test.drw</FILE>
                </FILES>
            </TEST>
            <TEST NEED_FUNCTION="true" FUNCTION_NAME="functionName456">
                <DESCRIPTION>
                    <DE>Hallo2</DE>
                    <EN>Hello2</EN>
                </DESCRIPTION>
                <FILES>
                </FILES>
            </TEST>
        </TESTSTEP>

    </TESTSTEPS>
</DSCT2C>
```

I want to count all `TEST` elements from a `TESTSTEP` element with for example `ORDER_NUMBER=0`. How can I do that with DOM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
    int n = 0;
    Document doc = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse(new File("1.xml"));
    NodeList list = doc.getElementsByTagName("TESTSTEP");
    for (int i = 0; i < list.getLength(); i++) {
        Element e = (Element) list.item(i);
        if (e.getAttribute("ORDER_NUMBER").equals("0")) {
            n += e.getElementsByTagName("TEST").getLength();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the xpath expression:

```
"//TESTSTEP[@ORDER_NUMBER = '0']/TEST"
```

Then get the length of the `NodeList` that's returned.

The code will look something like:

```
XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath()
NodeList tests = (NodeList)xpath.evaluate("//TESTSTEP[@ORDER_NUMBER = '0']/TEST", document, XPathConstants.NODESET);

int testCount = tests.getLength();
```

Comment: What is element in (NodeList)xpath.evaluate("//TESTSTEP[@ORDER_NUMBER = '0']/TEST", element, XPathConstants.NODESET);?

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo - you should just pass the document.